# Nodejs Neo4j ServiceUnavailable error

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher

I am playing around with neo4j enterprise edition v3.4.0 on aws ec2 t2.large instance with ubuntu OS.

I am trying to perform CRUD operation in neo4j using nodejs(npm: neo4j-driver)
The number of request that is being made is around 10000 in 20 seconds.
The problem I am facing here is after creating around 400 to 700 nodes, I get the error as response.

**Error** is : **{"code":"ServiceUnavailable","name":"Neo4jError"}**

While I can see that the server is still up and running as I am able to access everything and perform operation from web UI of neo4j.

Below is the screen shot: 
[image: Nodejs Neo4j ServiceUnavailable]

As you can see on the left hand side, only 2 request were successful from 10000 and on right hand side its 621 out of 10000.

The complete process is over within 20 seconds.
Also a help regarding the configuration of heap and page memory is much appreciated as right now I am using the default conf.

Today while going through logs, I found this error:

> ERROR Unable to schedule bolt session 'xxxxx' for execution since
>   there are no available thread-to serve it at the moment. You can retry
>   at a later time or consider increasing max thread pool size for bolt
>   connector(s).

Anyone have any idea how can I resolve this issue?

My runSession function code which is responsible for creating the nodes:

```
function runSession(query, params) {
    let driver = neo4j.driver(uri, neo4j.auth.basic(user, password));
    let session = driver.session();
    session
        .run(query, params)
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log("Success runSession:", /*JSON.stringify(result)*/);
            session.close();
            driver.close();
            session=null;
            driver=null;
            //success_count++;
            //console.log('success count:',success_count);
            //console.log('error count:',error_count)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error runSession:', JSON.stringify(error));
            session.close();
            driver.close();
            session=null;
            driver=null;
            //error_count++;
            //console.log('success count:',success_count);
            //console.log('error count:',error_count)
        });
}
```

Comment: Post your node code.  I'll bet what's happening is that when you get a result from the server, you're never closing it.  Or maybe you're creating lots of sessions or drivers and not closing them.  At any rate, what you're describing makes it sound like your code is creating a very large number of some resource X's, and never closing them when you're done, so when you run into problems is when you exhaust the pool

Comment: Hey thanks for replying.
Yes I am creating a very large number of create node requests,
I am closing the driver as well as session. I am adding the runSession function code in the above asked question itself.

Comment: @Guarav need the outer code too.  See the trouble with the code you've got right here is that it doesn't return the promise.  So the promise executes instantaneously -- callbacks happen later -- and if you're running that function in a loop, it's going to kick off hundreds or thusands of those and really beat the server up.   You probably need some promise coordination, where you use like bluebird Promise.map with concurrency.   If you're doing `for(var i=0;i<1000;i++){ runSession(); }` that' going to cause this problem